# JavaScript regular expression to match hyphenated words?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like a JavaScript regular expression that can match a string either at the start of another string, or after a hyphen in the string.

For example, "milne" and "lee" and "lees" should all match "Lees-Milne".

This is my code so far:

```
var name = "Lees-Milne";
var text = "lee";

// I don't know what 'text' is ahead of time, so 
// best to use RegExp constructor.
var re = RegExp("^" + text | "-" + text, "i");

alert(re.exec(name.toLowerCase()));
```

However, this returns null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to quote the bar, like this: `var re = RegExp("^" + text + "|-" + text, "i");` ?

Comment: No - thanks for pointing that out! Seems to solve the problem, though I'd still like any feedback on whether the overall regex looks sensible.

Comment: I think assuming that correction it looks fine.  I can't think of a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use:

```
var re = RegExp("(?:^|-)" + text, "i");
```

Don't forget to escape regex meta characters in `text` if it's not an expression it self.

JavaScript has no built in function for that, but you could use:

```
function quotemeta(str){
    return str.replace(/[.+*?|\\^$(){}\[\]-]/g, '\\$&');
}
```